# Facebook comment reply fails with "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later." through Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try to make a reply on a comment of a Facebook Page through the Facebook Graph API, but it always fails with

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 2
  }
}
```

Anyone has any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that the Facebook Page/User doesn't have Comment Replies enabled on his wall (probably because the page existed before the feature was introduced.)

To enable Comment Replies, please follow the steps in this document:
https://www.facebook.com/help/336467639799018